# Swift change class at runtime

Tags: ios, swift

So I have 3 views set up in interface builder (XCode 6). They are linked to the `ViewController` that owns them. Also I have 3 subclasses of `UIVIew` in my project. At runtime I would need to change the class of one of the views from `UIView` to my custom view subclass.

How do I do this in swift? (I need all the `autolayout` set up in IB to work the same after the change).

Comment: You can add required view in runtime. Use view in IB as container for custom view. Just set it's bounds to container size when you add it as subview.

Comment: good ideea... but I understand you can't use setFrame with autolayout (?)

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you need you can create a view in IB and later in the code add required view as a subview.

To make added view occupy all container view space you need either update child view's frame or setup auto-layout constraints. Variant with frames needs to be repeated each time container view changes it size. Code bellow:

#### Auto-Layout Contraints

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.myView = UIView(frame: CGRect())
    self.myView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.myViewContainer.addSubview(self.myView)

    self.myViewContainer.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.myView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.myViewContainer, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
    self.myViewContainer.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.myView, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.myViewContainer, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
    self.myViewContainer.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.myView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.myViewContainer, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
    self.myViewContainer.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.myView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.myViewContainer, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
}
```

#### Manual Frame Updates

```
@IBOutlet var myViewContainer: UIView
var myView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.myView = UIView(frame: CGRect())
    self.myViewContainer.addSubview(self.myView)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    self.myView.frame = self.myViewContainer.bounds
}
```

*Frame updates can be done even if container view has auto-layout constraints.*

Comment: So viewDidLayoutSubviews will be called automatically every time a rotation occurs ?

Comment: Yes if view controller supports rotation. Rotation cause size change which triggers re-layout.